# How to check all checkboxes according to each sub-input with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I've been sweating all day about this issue, and I've not found anything online to matches my need.

I have a html form with checkboxes as follows:

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="classes[]" value="1" />JSS1 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="subclasses[]" value="2" />Art <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="subclasses[]" value="1" />Science <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="classes[]" value="2" />JSS2 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="subclasses[]" value="1" />A <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="subclasses[]" value="2" />B <br>
```

Now, I want if I check a class (let's say JSS1) all the sub-classes under JSS1 (Art, Science) will be checked and so on..

How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: Please all the inputs are in a loop. Thanks

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer for [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/p13xkyL2/#&togetherjs=foLgdySzK7). Use this:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name^='classes']").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).siblings("input[name^='subclasses']").prop("checked", true);
            }
            else {
                $(this).siblings("input[name^='subclasses']").prop("checked", false);
            }
        });

    });
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="classes[]" value="1" />JSS1 <br>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="subclasses[]" value="2" />Art <br>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="subclasses[]" value="1" />Science <br>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="classes[]" value="2" />JSS2 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="subclasses[]" value="1" />A <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="subclasses[]" value="2" />B <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Yaaaaaah! Worked like charm. Thanks a lot @vispan.

Comment: But how do I uncheck the parent Class if one of it's subclasses is unchecked?

Comment: I've solved it with: $(this).siblings("input[name^='classes']").prop("checked", false);